# Hard drive unallocated after misuse of dd command

Tags: hard-drive, partition-recovery

I tried to create a bootable USB using the command:

`dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb`

and I made a mistake. I typed sdb instead sdd. sdb being my second hard drive and sdd my USB drive.

I canceled the operation, but my hard drive is invisible now. Back in Windows 7, the Disk Management tool displays this hard drive with 3 sections, 2GB unallocated followed by 2MB healthy followed by 400 something GB unallocated.

Is there any way to recover my drive to the previous state after this mishap?

Answer (score 0):

Boot your computer with a LiveCD (such as Ubuntu or Knoppix) and run the gparted partition editor. It will show you all your existing devices and partitions. Resize/Recreate your partition on the sdb device using gparted tool and then format it with ntfs/ext4/etc.

If you want to recover your lost data, then you may skip resizing and instead try your luck with tools available with Knoppix or similar recovery distributions, but I don't think there is much hope there - dd command writes directly to the device stream.

If you want the disk partition to be visible in your windows-7 OS, then be sure to format with ntfs and not anything else.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the dd command only wrote to the 2GB part of the disk that was supposed to be the Ubuntu image. The rest of the disk was not changed apart of the partition structure. In that case it should be possible to somehow read the data or maybe declare that the rest, 400 something GB part, is a partition without formatting it. I found _testdisk_ and _photorec_ and will give it a try. Do you maybe have some experience with this tools?

Comment: Some months back, I had some success with recovering deleted files with Recuva. You can try that: http://www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: Some more tools are listed here: http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/DD/recovery_of_lost_files_using_dd.shtml

Comment: Cool, thanks for your help. _Photorec_ found and could recover the files, but not the folder structure. After that I found another software that managed to sense that structure also and it is copying the data to an external drive at the moment.

I was correct, the _dd_ command only did some damage and I am able to recover all the data with an exception of 2GB of files.

SOLVED
Have a nice day, I know I will :)